# Are there any good tools to remember commonly used CLI commands?

Tags: linux, command-line

I've got a lot of commands that I run frequently like:

> sometool --environment=dev command=fetch foo/bar/baz/configfile
>
> sometool --environment=dev command=update foo/bar/baz/configfile
>
> sometool --environment=dev command=status

Is there any tool that I can configure with a list of common commands as well as have some options for editing them intelligently (like if i wanted to use a different value for `--environment` there).

Better still would be if it could be path sensitive so I could have different sets of commands depending where I am.

Comment: Have you considered aliases?

Comment: Aliases aren't very good for things that change or I need to choose one of the parameters from a list. They also don't offer any way to see all the aliases that are currently useful.

Comment: Reading only the question's title, the shell's history mechanism came immediately to my mind.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-history-search-command/ and http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/08/15-examples-to-master-linux-command-line-history/

Answer (score 4):

You don't mention your shell - this really is shell dependent.

In most shells, you can do aliases and functions. This can reduce a lot of your typing for either repeated commands, or repeated subsets of commands.

aliases are better for repeated commands. functions can take arguments, so are more powerful for when you have similar, but not exact copies of commands.

Personally, I also configure bash-completions for stuff like this. For example, I have a subdirectory that has directories of all my working projects. I have completions for various actions on the projects (check if files are checked out for the project, create an install bundle, etc.)

For bash completion.  You write a function that can examine the current argument, the previous argument, and the command line, and figure out what makes sense in the current context. You then attach that function to the wanted command with the `complete` bash builtin.

'What makes sense in the current context' can be anything - it can be directories, files, other arguments. anything at all. Check the examples in the [bash-completions](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) bundle to see some examples.

The bash completion code was borrowed from zsh, so if you have zsh, you'll be able to use this too. In fact the bash completion code was borrowed early from zsh, and zsh expanded past that, so zsh completion is arguably more powerful.

Comment: I do use bash currently, but I'd be willing to change.

I've used aliases extensively, but they're only really good for static commands.

I'll look into completions to see if it does what I want. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @murph it goes 'alias' => 'function' => 'bash completions' both in usefulness/flexibility, and order of complexity to create.

Comment: @Murph An alias like `alias foo='echo $bar'` is still static, but can be influenced easily .

Comment: @mpy yeah, forgot about that (upvoted)... remember, single quotes makes the variable interpolated at execution time, not at profile reading time.

Answer (score 1):

ncurses comes to mind, it takes some effort to learn it but then you have a menu system for exactly that purpose.

Edit: ncurses allow menu-based navigation, accept user input, it was created for the CLI, and able to store base commands, allow regexp expansion. Many Linux distro use the curses library with sequence-based selection choices during install, and run other commands in response - what and when maybe monitored on the next single-user console using Alt-function, such as Alt-F2, so the intended outcome maybe monitored and the script debug.

I used it when I was learning to program Visual Basic for DOS, and when I started learning Linux I built a few trying to imitate the VB DOS text-menus and functions.

Comment: Short answers are generally not a good format for Super User. Could you expand on how a user could use ncurses for his purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Use an editor and stick useful commands in a file. I have an alias called 'b' that opens/edits the file. No need to overengineer this one.